# Is there a way to get airline prices from the past?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, price

I traveled from Frankfurt to Japan in July for an office work. However, as my employer is based in Vienna, I always need to provide some price comparison (in form of a screenshot) for comparable flights from Vienna to the final destination. However, I can't find the screenshot anymore and I am desperately searching for a way to 'recover' prices I would have paid for this flight originally in order to get my flights reimbursed. Is there any way or service which could provide me previous date flights prices?

Comment: Finding a list of prices available on a certain route on a certain day in the past would be nigh impossible.  I seriously doubt anyone keeps a day by day record of seat availability which would in turn determine which fare buckets were shown that day.  At best you might find fares that had been filed with authorities for that route and time period.

Comment: Should “employee” be “employer”?

Comment: Can you find the actual amount you paid, e.g. via a booking confirmation or bank statement? Wouldn't this be better for reimbursement, instead of the price for a comparable flight?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @HenricF. This would definitely be a better approach but the fare I paid did cover a flight from a different departure airport - my employer grants me reimbursement for comparable flights starting from our local airport.

Comment: @muffin1974 I see! Hope you find a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several websites which provide historical fare comparisons.  However, all have gaps in their coverage, and tend to focus more heavily on US domestic flights.  However, it is certainly possible one of these sites might have the record you look for.

You can find many of these sites by simply googling "historical fare comparison", but there is quite a helpful list in the answer to [this Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-websites-if-any-provide-historical-airline-ticket-prices).